# OpenMP for beginners

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I just got started with openMP; I wrote a little C code in order to check if what I have studied is correct. However I found some troubles; here is the *main.c* code

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "omp.h"
#include "time.h"

int main(){

float msec_kernel;
const int N = 1000000;
int i, a[N];

clock_t start = clock(), diff;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++){
    a[i] = 2 * i;
}
diff = clock() - start;
msec_kernel = diff * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
printf("Kernel Time: %e s\n",msec_kernel*1e-03);
printf("a[N] = %d\n",a[N]);
return 0;
}
```

My goal is to see how long it takes to the PC to do such operation using 1 and 2 CPUs; in order to to compile the program I type the following line in the terminal:

```
gcc -fopenmp main.c -o main
```

And then I select the number of CPUs like so:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=N
```

where N is either 1 or 2; however I don't get the right execution time; my results in fact are:

```
Kernel Time: 5.000000e-03 s
a[N] = 2000000
```

and

```
Kernel Time: 6.000000e-03 s
a[N] = 2000000
```

Both corresponding to N=1 and N=2. as you can see when I use 2 CPUs it takes slightly more time than using just one! What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using `clock()` on Linux to get the wall time. Use `omp_get_wtime()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using multiple cores doesn't implicitly mean, that you're going to get better performance.

OpenMP has to manage the data distribution among you're cores which is going to take time as well. Especially for very basic operations such as only a single multiplication you are doing, performance of a sequential (single core) program will be better.

Second, by going through every element of you're array only once and not doing anything else, you make no use of cache memory and most certainly not of shared cache between cpu's.

So you should start reading some things about general algorithm performance. To make use of multiple cores using shared cache is in my opinion the essence.
Todays computers have come to a stage where the CPU is so much faster than a memory allocation, read or write. This means when using multiple cores, you'll only have a benefit if you use things like shared cache, because the data distribution,initialization of the threads and managing them will use time as well. To really see a performance [speedup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) (See the link, essential term in parallel computing) you should program an algorithm which has a heavy accent on computation not on memory; this has to do with [locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) (another important term).

So if you wanna experience a big performance boost by using multiple cores test it on a matrix-matrix-multiplication on big matrices such as 10'000*10'000. And plot some graphs with inputsize(matrix-size) to time and matrix-size to [gflops](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_Point_Operations_Per_Second) and compare the multicore with the sequential version.

Also make yourself comfortable with the complexity analysis (Big O notation).
Matrix-matrix-multiplication has a locality of O(n).

Hope this helps :-)

I suggest setting the numbers of cores/threads within the code itself either directly at the #pragma line `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)` or using the omp_set_num_threads function `omp_set_num_threads(2);`

Further, when doing time/performance analysis it is really important to always run the program multiple times and then take the mean of all the runtimes or something like that. Running the respective programs only once will not give you a meaningful reading of used time. Always call multiple times in a row. Not to forget to also alternate the quality of data.

I suggest writing a test.c file, which takes your actual program function within a loop and then calculates the time per execution of the function:

```
int executiontimes = 20;
clock_t initial_time = clock();
for(int i = 0; i < executiontimes; i++){
    function_multiplication(values);    
}
clock_t final_time = clock();
clock_t passed_time = final_time - initial_time;
clock_t time_per_exec = passed_time / executiontimes;
```

Improve this test algorithm, add some rand() for your values etc. seed them with srand() etc. If you have more questions on the subject or to my answer leave a comment and I'll try to explain further by adding more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The function `clock()` returns elapsed CPU time, which includes ticks from all cores. Since there is some overhead to using multiple threads, when you sum the execution time of all threads the total cpu time will always be longer than the serial time.

If you want the *real time* (wall clock time), try to use the OMP Runtime Library function `omp_get_wtime()` defined in `omp.h`. It is cross platform portable and should be the preferred way to do wall timing.

You can also use the POSIX functions defined in `time.h`:

```
struct timespec start, stop;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
// action
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
double elapsed_time = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + 
                      1e-9 * (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
```